# Clamav installation steps for linux centos

Tags: installation, centos, antivirus

I have tried to install clamav in linux centos, but not able to succeed, so anybody provide me the procedure to install clamav antivirus and test the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://nsinfra.blogspot.in/2011/06/java-api-to-detect-virus-using-clamav.html

Answer (score 1):

- First thing to do is install the program sudo apt-get install clamav
- It´s necessary install the deamon program as well  sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon
- Once that we have the program properly installed, will be necessary configure to make it works with our app. /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
      TCPAddr 127.0.0.1
  TCPSocket 3310
- To configure by console the antivirus just type sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
  Restart the service sudo /etc/init.d/clamv-* restart

Answer (score 1):

## For CentOS 6

## Install ClamAV via yum epel repo:

```
yum install clamd
```

## Edit config file:

```
vim /etc/clamd.conf
    ExtendedDetectionInfo yes
    ExcludePath /usr/local/maldetect/
    DetectPUA yes
```

## Set to start on boot:

```
chkconfig clamd on
```

## Update ClamAV prior to a scan:

```
freshclam
```

## Start ClamAV:

```
service clamd start
```

## Add the cron for daily automatic scans:

```
vim /etc/cron.daily/daily-clamscan
    #!/bin/bash
    SCAN_DIR="/"
    LOG_FILE="/var/log/clamav/daily-clamscan.log"
    /usr/bin/clamscan -i -r $SCAN_DIR >> $LOG_FILE
```

## Set proper cron permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/daily-clamscan
```

## Update the logrotate file to look for all logs via wildcard

```
vim /etc/logrotate.d/daily-clamscan
    /var/log/clamav/daily-clamscan.log {
            missingok
            notifempty
            create 644 clam clam
    }
```

Thats how I installed it on my machine. Here are a few good quick commands or you can use the cron to manually run it. I also installed Linux Malware Detect (LMD) with it so I can do more for my scans.

## Full System Scan that only displays infected files and runs in the background with bell

## Use `jobs` command to view status

```
clamscan -r --bell -i / &
```